# Javascript to ClojureScript Conversion

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I am trying to convert the following line to Cljs,

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy:  true });
```

What would be the corresponding map for,

```
{ enableHighAccuracy:  true }
```

in ClojureScript? Is enableHighAccuracy a symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using interop with a library (such as geolocation, in your case), and it expects a JavaScript object, you'll need to pass it a standard JavaScript object, not a Clojure map.

You can construct one of these in ClojureScript by using the `js-obj` function with no arguments. This will return an empty JavaScript with no fields; you can then add fields using the `aset` function.

So your code would be something like:

```
(let [arg (js-obj)]
  (aset arg "enableHighAccuracy" true)
  (.watchPosition (.geolocation navigator) on-success on-error arg))
```

If this is something you find yourself doing a lot, it's easy to write a utility function to convert a ClojureScript map into a JavaScript object using whatever defaults you like; an example of such a function can be found in this gist; https://gist.github.com/1658431